# Standing waves, frequency and speed of sound

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

Would frequency of a standing wave in a tube change if the speed of sound was changed? For example, if temperature was increased from 30 degrees Celsius to 20, how would the the frequency of a standing wave in a tube change?

Comment: Hello Mick and welcome to Physics SE. Does this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/756637/220866 answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused regarding the wavelength of standing waves and their relation with wave speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/756632/confused-regarding-the-wavelength-of-standing-waves-and-their-relation-with-wave)